# Error NodeJS : Cannot get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'll try to be as clear as I can be. So I'm trying to make a little plateform. I would like that someone connect to the page (in localhost) and then, have the possibility to click on a button, and this button will redirect him to another html page.

So I have a project folder with my "initial" html, my app.js file, and the other html file, which should show itself when clicking on the button.

The server works like this :

```
    var application = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(application),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    ent = require('ent'),
    fs = require('fs');

application.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});
```

and then, I have the button :

```
<a href="pfc.html" target="_blank"> <input type="button" value="blah"></a>
```

When launching "node app.js" on the terminal, I go on the page, click on the the button and then I got the error "Cannot GET /pfc.html".

Sorry if I'm quite not understandable, I hope someone will understand me.

Thanks and have a nice day!!

Comment: Typo? It's [`sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) (capital `F`) not `sendfile`. Capitalization matters. I'd be expecting you to see an error on the Node side when you did the GET, though.

Comment: pfc.html is a static file, you should search for "nodejs static file serving" and start there. Someone will probably answer with something similar, but you may be able to work it out yourself with that.

Comment: Are you sure you have pfc.html file, as your route for `/` is on the server that sends `index.html`, but where are you handling the click for pfc.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote some code to tell your server what to do if the browser asks for `/`

> ```
> application.get('/', function (req, res) {
>   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
> });
> ```

Then you wrote a link:

> ```
> <a href="pfc.html"
> ```

which makes the browser ask for `/pfx.html`.

You haven't written anything in the server side code to tell it how to respond to a request for that. You've only told it how to respond to a request for `/`.

You could write something similar (`application.get('/pfx.html',...`) or find some existing middleware for handling static files.

Comment: Ah yes. So the `sendfile` typo will be the **next** problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple HTML files like `pfc.html`, you can use

```
application.use(express.static('public'));
```

and keep all your html files (including `pfc.html`) in a folder named `public` and all those html files that you serve like:

```
<a href="pfc.html"></a>
```

you can look for them at `public/pfc.html` and such. If the file exists, then the application won't return stuff like `Cannot GET /pfc.html` and you won't need to write explicit routes for all of them.

Comment: It's working thank you! I'm feeling stupid not thinking about it earlier I was working on it for 3 hours!!

Comment: It happens to even the best of us @RomainEntakli :) I'm glad that you found the solution, I'm glad that I could help.